# Check all variables if one of them contains number

Tags: python

I need to check all variables if one of them contains number 6

```
def func(a, b, c, d, e, f):
```

If True print Yes
If False print No

Comment: Please provide your work so far. This is no place where somebody will do your homework, but rather help You when You hit a wall.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a do-my-homework service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def func(a, b, c, d, e, f):
  if any(num for num in [a,b,c,d,e,f] if num == 6):
      print "Yes"
  else:
      print "No"
```

Comment: If you insist on answering homework questions, please at least post a sane answer. And while we're at it, you may want to read this https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence